# Using 2D servo array in my class

Tags: servo, array, class

I need to use a servo library in my class.
I read this question - [Use object of other class within class](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/9296/use-object-of-other-class-within-class) and it works fine for my LCD application, but now I need to use a 2D servo array in my class. I made one approach, it worked, but I think it is bad programming approach, what is right way to solve my problem?

1. My main file

   ```cpp
   #include <SoftwareServo.h> 
   SoftwareServo servo[5][5];
   Servolib Servoarray;

   void setup(){
     blah blah blah
   ```
2. My cpp file

   ```cpp
   #include "Vending.h"
   #include "Arduino.h"
   #include <SoftwareServo.h>

   Servolib::TurnSevo(){
     for(int row=0;row<5;row++){
       for(int collum=0;collum<5;collum++){
         servo[row][collum].attach(Object[row][collum]);
         servo[row][collum].write(0);
       }
     }
   }
   ```
3. my .h file

   ```cpp
   #ifndef Vending_h
   #define Vending_h
   #include "Arduino.h"
   #include <SoftwareServo.h>

   class Servolib:SoftwareServo{
   public:
     void TurnServo();

   private:
     SoftwareServo servo[5][5];
     int Object[5][5]={
       {42,21,20,19,18},
       {37,41,36,38,35},
       {31,33,30,34,39},
       {67,28,66,29,65},
       {56,63,55,64,54}
     };
   };
   #endif
   ```

So this code worked, but please give me better solution.

Comment: What do you feel is wrong with that, please?  I could suggest you use a `#define` or a `const int` for your array dimensions, rather than having so-called "magic numbers" in the code, but apart from that it looks fine to me. (Also you spelled column wrong, but really this is nit-picking.)

Comment: I though i could pass servo object address and work with pointers, similar to this example -> http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/9296/use-object-of-other-class-within-class , but i don't know how to pass 2D array using pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed use pointers, but passing multi-dimensional arrays is a bit of a pain in C(++).

There's a pretty good explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-a-2d-array-to-a-c-function).